# Pre-populating checkbox fields in a CloudPage in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, form, cloudpage

I'm currently building a preferences update form (not the main default Marketing Cloud preferences centre, but a specific form for a small audience segment)

I'm pre-populating the form from a personalised link in an email. I've been able to pre-populate the text fields with their existing preferences like so:

```
<input type="text" id="Firstname" name="Firstname" value="%%=v(@Firstname)=%%" required="" required>
```

But I am struggling a little with the checkboxes (boolean).

In raw HTML, adding 'checked' as below pre-ticks the checkbox. I've stored this value based on an if statement in a variable

```
If IndexOf(@StudyRegion,@Region1) > 0 Then
    Set @RegionNE = "checked"
Else
    Set @RegionNE = ""
EndIf
```

So if they checked that box first time round, the IndexOf section of the query finds it in the string (created as a result of multiple checkboxes) which looks like 'Northern Ireland,Wales,Greater London,East Midlands' etc. If it finds the appropriate region it sets the RegionNE variable to 'checked'. I have tried putting this variable in the checkbox lines like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Study region" id="North East" value="North East" %%=v(@RegionNE)=%% />
```

But it's clearly wrong as it causes the page to get a 500 error. What would be the right way of making this checkbox be checked if the variable was found to be 'checked'?

Comment: Are the variables StudyRegion and Region1 defined in your code.  If either of these variables are null, I would guess it would result in a 500 error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@TCassa, your approach appears correct.  I've taken this approach many time before.  I suspect it is just something minor in your code like a syntax issue or undefined variable.

**Suggestion:**
I've started using a new approach in this scenario by using the [IIF() function](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/iif/#iif).  This approach allows me to place the **AMPScript** code inline with my HTML.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Study region" id="North East" value="North East" %%=IIF(@StudyRegion=="North East"," checked ","")=%%/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this - what are the double equals == for in the IIf? the cloudpages code has turned it light red.

Comment: This is conditional comparison logic.  The syntax is correct.  reference: http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_langauge_elements/